# Cast cv::Mat to ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, casting

**Doubt:**

Is there an easy way to cast `cv::Mat` to [`ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>`](http://www.uni-koblenz.de/~puma/dox-dev/puma/html/classipcMatrix.html)?

Comment: Please add the **c++** tag to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret to convert `cv::Mat` to another data type, is understanding how the data (pixels) is stored and ordered:

- OpenCV stores data in a `cv::Mat` as an array of `unsigned char`, and pixels are stored in the **BGR** order;
- `ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>` works pretty much in the same way, except pixels are stored as **RGB**;

That said, to convert a `cv::Mat` into `ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>` all you need to do is:

```
// Load input image
cv::Mat mat_input = cv::imread("input.jpg");

// Convert a BGR Mat into RGB:
cv::Mat mat_rgb;
cv::cvtColor(mat_input, mat_rgb, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

// Copy the pixels from the Mat to another memory location:
int data_sz = mat_rgb.rows * mat_rgb.cols * mat_rgb.channels();
unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char[data_sz];    
memcpy(pixels, mat_rgb.data, data_sz);

// And finally, use the constructor of ipcMatrix<> to declare the new object correctly:
ipcMatrix<ipcRGB> input = ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>(mat_rgb.cols, mat_rgb.rows, (ipcRGB*)pixels);
```